# what is EntityMode in hibernate 3.2?

Tags: hibernate

What is  entity mode ?.Actually i trying to find out the primary key in the table using hibernate.

```
ClassMetadata metaData=mapSession.getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(Dept.class);
metaData.getIdentifierPropertyName();
```

Its displaying primay key column.But i trying to display primary key column with values using getIdentifier(Object,EntityMode).

How to use entity mode in getIdentifier method?Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The org.hibernate.EntityMode defines the representation modes available for entities.

Packages that use EntityMode

org.hibernate

org.hibernate.cache

org.hibernate.cfg

org.hibernate.collection

org.hibernate.engine

org.hibernate.event.def
org.hibernate.impl

org.hibernate.mapping

org.hibernate.metadata

org.hibernate.persister.entity

org.hibernate.pretty

org.hibernate.property

org.hibernate.tuple

org.hibernate.tuple.component

org.hibernate.tuple.entity

org.hibernate.type

Thanks